getting a Trying to access array offset on value of type null error on PHP
I am getting this error:

Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in
/var/www/html/wp-content/themes/eventalk/functions.php on line 721
Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in
/var/www/html/wp-content/themes/eventalk/functions.php on line 734

Here is the code:
<a class="'; if ($first) $html .= 'active'; $html .= '" href="#class-'.$row["term_id"].'" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="'; $html .= ($first) ? 'true' : 'false'; $first=false; $html .= '">
  <h3>Year ' . $year . '</h3>
</a><div><ul>';

and the other code:
 <a class="'; if ($first) $html .= 'active'; $html .= '" href="#class-'.$row["term_id"].'" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="'; $html .= ($first) ? 'true' : 'false'; $first=false; $html .= '">
  <h4>Starting in ' . $month_name . '</h4>
</a><div><ul>';

Does any one know how to solve this problem?

Have you tried to research or debug this error? I'd guess it's because $row is null, and therefore you can't access any array elements within it (such as $row["term_id"]) because it isn't an array. As to why $row is null here, of course we cannot tell you because we know nothing about that variable in your code, such as how or where it's supposed to be defined and populated.

Can you please print_r($first) then you check is empty or not

is empty @Rahul

$first has nothing to do with this, the array access is happening on $row, not $first.
